# Out[] is returning percent sign % instead of expression 10.3

Tags: core-language

Has anyone else had this problem, is it a setting, or a bug in 10.3?

```
In[1]:= 2;
        %+2
Out[2]= %1+2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on MMA 10.3 (Win7-64bit). Have you tried restarting the kernel, the whole MMA session, or possibly trying a [clean start](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)?

Comment: You have likely set `$HistoryLength=0`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I had just quit the kernel and that solved the issue. I was using someone else's notebook and they must have had $HistoryLength=0 in an initialization cell. Problem's solved.

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith Would you mind answering your own question including @Szabolcs suggestion (it is encouraged in SE)? `$HistoryLength` had not occurred to me first, and I think it would be useful to have this question show up as answered for future users that might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As @Szabolcs pointed out, `$HistoryLength` mush have been set to 0. I was using someone else's notebook on the same kernel and it caused my `%` statements to not return the expression but `%n` instead. Restarting the kernel worked; the problem would return if I evaluated the other user's notebook.